# Update attribute when an object is added/removed from a relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Consider this model:

```
@class Patient;

@interface Hospital : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * patientCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *patients;
@end

@interface Hospital (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPatientsObject:(Patient *)value;
- (void)removePatientsObject:(Patient *)value;
- (void)addPatients:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePatients:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

I want to update `patientCount` every time a patient is added or removed. If this was a normal attribute I would simple override the setters/getters, but since they were generated by Core Data, I don't know how to do it.

What's to correct way? I don't want to fetch the patients just to count them and I don't want to use KVO for something this simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware you can get patient count directly from hospital.patients.count ?  Why bother keeping an attribute for this ?

But if you must, then implement methods similar to these in your managedObjectSubclass and update the relevant attribute within these methods.

```
    - (void)addTasksObject:(TreeNode *)value {    
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"tasks" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"tasks"] addObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"tasks" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        // Add code to update self.patientsCount here
        self.patientsCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.patientsCount intValue] + 1];
    }

    - (void)removeTasksObject:(TreeNode *)value {
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"tasks" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"tasks"] removeObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"tasks" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        // Add code to update self.patientsCount here (better check not negative)
        self.patientsCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.patientsCount intValue] - 1];
    }

    - (void)addTasks:(NSSet *)value {    
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"tasks" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"tasks"] unionSet:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"tasks" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
        self.patientsCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.patients.count];
    }

    - (void)removeTasks:(NSSet *)value {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"tasks" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"tasks"] minusSet:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"tasks" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
        self.patientsCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.patients.count];
    }
```

Comment: Problem is, if I do a count, Core Data will hit the disk to fetch the relationship even if all objects are faulted, which is something I want to avoid. Also, doesn't the code need to set the reverse relationship?

Comment: The Knuth quote applies here I think, the one about premature optimization. I would imagine that CoreData is smart enough to handle this. If you really are sure you need to do this, you should look at things like the CachedAggregate Design Pattern, or Agents in Akka as an example of what is required.

Comment: I don't believe you need to set the reverse relationship, best test it out to confirm that though.  With the exception of the lines illustrating the setting of the patientsCount attribute the code comes from a working app.  I believe this code was generated by XCode when I generated subclasses from the core data entities.  Again - try generating the subclasses yourself using XCode and see if you get the same methods.

Comment: @Rob You were right. I decided to seed the app with a few dozen hospitals containing a thousand patients each and even using count Core Data didn't even blink at it.

Comment: Don't you also have to account for whether the object was actually added to the set? If the object already exists in the set then it won't actually be added and doing the +1 would invalidate the count. Same goes for removals.