# CoreData fetch with NSSortDescriptor by count of to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have 2 CoreData entities (Person, Pet) with the following relationship:

A Person can have multiple Pets.  So, there is a To-Many relationship from Person->Pet.

I want to fetch all Persons, sorted by the count of Pets that they have where the person with the most Pets is first, and the person with the fewest Pets is last.

When fetching a list of Persons, I tried using an NSSortDescriptor like the following:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pets.count" ascending:NO]
```

I thought that the "pets" property on a "person" would allow me to use the count property of NSSet to sort.  Alas, CoreData complains with this error:

```
Fetch exception to-many key not allowed here
```

Is this a completely wrong approach?  How am I supposed to do something like this with a CoreData fetch?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using [collection operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html):

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pets.@count" ascending:NO]
```

This can't be applied directly though (to a fetch request), you need to execute the fetch and then run the sort on the result array (`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`).

If you want to sort while fetching, you would need to add a (non-transient) attribute to the entity which holds the count number.

Comment: Your answer works for sorting after the fetch, which is fine in my situation since the list is never going to be more than a few dozen items, max.  Thanks!

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839265/nssortdescriptor-with-to-many-relationship), this can't be done.

Comment: @jab, in fact I say that it can't be done in the data store, you have to fetch first and then sort (or add extra information to the data store).

Comment: Please be more specific @iDev750

Comment: @Wain If I'm applying above line of code, it's crashing.

Comment: @iDev750 you should probably create a new question so you can give context about what you're running and what the crash is

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of your key to `@"pets.@count"`

Comment: I just tried that, and I get a different exception:  Fetch exception Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle pets.@count

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20317087/2567126

Basically you create a persistent property on the NSManagedObject and update the property count any time a child object is added or removed from the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I also need to do the same thing but in Swift. I just to follow:

1. Fetch the request from CoreData without 'count' key-value.
2. I performed sort (high order function) on the fetched result.

```
allCategory.sort { (category1, category2) -> Bool in
            return category1.tasks?.count > category2.tasks?.count
        }
```

This is working for me.