# Sort Array of FetchedObjects From Core Data by Number of Reviews in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I would like to sort an array of Reviews fetched from Core Data by the number of times a given book is reviewed.  The Entity is reviews and the review entity has an attribute bookid.  So for the following table:

```
reviewid|bookid|review
1|1|This is a great novel...
2|1|Wonderful novel
3|2|Ok biography.
4|3|Horrible romance
```

I would like to return an array that has bookid=1 at the top as it has two reviews whereas the others have one.

How can I do this using NSSortDescriptor?

I believe, you can do it to the array after the fetch using the following but it seems that it should be possible to do it directly in the core data results

```
NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:reviews];
NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"bookid.@count" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
NSArray *sortedArray  = [results sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the NSFetchRequest's sort descriptor.

```
request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor]
```

Read the documentation for more info.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506262-sortdescriptors

Comment: It should but I am not 100% sure. Why not try and let us know :)

Comment: It does not. Not for me or according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531319/coredata-fetch-with-nssortdescriptor-by-count-of-to-many-relationship